# Transform Multiple xml input source as stream to one xslt using saxon

Tags: saxon

I am new to saxon and xslt, we have business in which feeder delivere more than one xml files, xslt generated from altov) create one output xml files , we have selected saxon as transformer.

so far i am able to transform single xml file

do any body have example where xslt takes more than one xmls as input stream, transform using saxon.

Thanks & regards,
Kumar

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?  You will get better responses if you can show what you've already attempted.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us enough about the requirements, but there are several techniques to be aware of:

- You can pass additional documents as stylesheet parameters declared using xsl:param
- You can read a document (given its URI) using the doc() or document() functions
- You can read a whole collection of documents (e.g. the contents of a directory) using the collection() function